# Error: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to import txt file into sql, but i have an error:

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

My code:

```
import psycopg2
con = psycopg2.connect(
        host = "",
        database="",
        user = "",
        password = "")
cursor = con.cursor()

with open("pom1.txt") as infile:
for line in infile:
    data = line.split()
    print(data)
    query = ("INSERT INTO Pomiary_Obwod_90(Znacznik, Pomiar_x, Pomiar_y, Pomiar_z) VALUES"
             "(" + data + ");")
    cursor.execute(query, *data)
    con.commit()
```

Does anyone have an idea how can i solve it? :)

Comment: Well, `data` is a list of strings, not a string. You could use `', '.join` to create a comma separated list, but this isn't how you create a parameterized query.

Comment: `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Pomiary_Obwod_90(Znacznik, Pomiar_x, Pomiar_y, Pomiar_z) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s), data)`

Comment: Always share the entire error message. What do you understand from that error message? I would recommend reading the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here. First, as the error says, you are trying to concatenate a `List` (which is `data`) directly to a string.

Second, you should not use `+` to concatenate your values and your query.

The [doc](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html) says:

> Warning: Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.

You should only pass the values to the query via `%s`.

I'm not sure about the use of `*` in front of `data` in `cursor.execute(query, *data)`.

Here is a code that should work, though I have nothing at hand for testing it right now:

```
import psycopg2
con = psycopg2.connect(
        host = "",
        database="",
        user = "",
        password = "")
cursor = con.cursor()

with open("pom1.txt") as infile:
for line in infile:
    data = line.split()
    print(data)
    query = ("INSERT INTO Pomiary_Obwod_90(Znacznik, Pomiar_x, Pomiar_y, Pomiar_z) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s);")
    cursor.execute(query, data)
    con.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't put the actual values into the parameterized query; you put whatever placeholders are appropriate for your library.

```
data = line.split()
place_holders = ', '.join("%s" for _ in data)  # Assuming %s is correct
query = ("INSERT INTO Pomiary_Obwod_90(Znacznik, Pomiar_x, Pomiar_y, Pomiar_z) VALUES"
         "(" + place_holders + ");")
cursor.execute(query, *data)
```

`cursor.execute` takes care of inserting each value where a placeholder occurs, ensure things are properly quoted/escaped/etc.